# Private pointer in class doesn't update when changed in method

Tags: c++

I have these classes (stripped for readability)

```
class node {
   public:
   int x;
   node* next;

   node(){}
   ~node(){}
 };

 class intLinkedList{
     public:
         intLinkedList();
         ~intLinkedList();

         void Add (int newX);

     private:
         node* root;
  };
```

This is the implementation in Add

```
void intLinkedList::Add (int newX){
  node* newNode = new node();
  newNode->x = newX;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  std::cout << "\n\n" << root << "\n\n" << std::flush;

  if (root == NULL){
    root = newNode;    
    return;
  }

  node * current;
  current = root;

  while (current->next != NULL){
    current = current->next;
  }

  current->next = newNode;

  return;
}
```

When I printout the address pointed to by root immediately after setting it, it shows a valid address.  However, the next time I call Add, root has become NULL again.  I cannot imagine what behavior is causing this.  This is used absolutely nowhere else.

I fully realize that there is something simple I'm missing.  If your inclination is to down vote because the problem is simple, take it elsewhere.  The purpose of this platform is for coders to come together to help each other when we have coding brainfarts.

EDIT:  This is the driver.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "intLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

void AddValue(intLinkedList MyList);
void GetValue(intLinkedList MyList);
void InsertValue(intLinkedList MyList);
void DeleteValue(intLinkedList MyList);
void PrintList(intLinkedList MyList);

int main(){
    intLinkedList MyList;
    int Option;

    while (true){

        cout << "\n\nMain Menu\n---------\n\n1) Add Value\n2) See Value\n3)     Insert Value at Position\n4) Delete Value at Position\n5) Print List\n6)     Exit\n\n";
    cin >> Option;

        switch (Option){
            case 1: AddValue(MyList); break;
            case 2: GetValue(MyList); break;
            case 3: InsertValue(MyList); break;
            case 4: DeleteValue(MyList); break;
            case 5: PrintList(MyList); break;
            case 6: exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void AddValue(intLinkedList MyList){
    int NewValue;
    cout << "What value should be added?\n";
    cin >> NewValue;

    MyList.Add(NewValue);
}

void GetValue(intLinkedList MyList){
    int Position;
    cout << "What position do you want the value of?\n";
    cin >> Position;

    MyList.Get(Position);
}

void InsertValue(intLinkedList MyList){
    int Position;
    int NewValue;
    cout << "What position do you wnat to insert after?\n";
    cin >> Position;
    cout << "\nWhat value do you want to insert?\n";
    cin >> NewValue;

    MyList.Insert(NewValue, Position);
}

void DeleteValue(intLinkedList MyList){
    int Position;
    cout << "What position do you want to delete?\n";
    cin >> Position;

    MyList.Delete(Position);
}

void PrintList(intLinkedList MyList){
    cout << MyList.Print();
}
```

Comment: We don't downvote because the problem is simple, we downvote because of other criteria (i.e a question doesn't contain a concise reproducible program (like yours)).

Comment: Most people here are super helpful and I love it, but I have had some problems when I've asked questions deemed noobish.   

Comment: "stripped for readability" Don't do this, who's to say you aren't clobbering the stack somewhere else. [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code does not exhibit the behavior you are describing.  You've removed whatever is causing the error when you "stripped for readability"

Comment: I only execute the Add method.   It's a simple driver program to treat why this is happening.   (I did remove a second cout line to verify the value of root after setting it.)   The constructor is empty (for both) and nothing else executes.

Comment: Please show the simple driver program

Comment: Even if something doesn't appear to be causing the problem, or even remotely related to it, it could have a domino effect that causes the issue you're trying to solve.  Please test your example code as posted in this question, with the same compiler used to compile the original code, to see if it causes the problem: if it does, try with a different compiler (using Clang, GCC, and VS online compilers if necessary), and see if the problem still occurs; if it doesn't, please post the original code here.

Comment: I should add that I'm using g++ in Ubuntu 14.04.  I've compiled with the other class as empty and only the Add function implemented  (Basically as it is here but with empty methods for intLinkedList

Comment: @user657267 You know that nice `[MCVE]` magic thing? Saves a lotta time typing and composing the link.

Comment: @C_Rod _"I should add that I'm using g++ in Ubuntu 14.04"_ No, that's irrelevant in your case. Just fire up your code in the debugger and step through, and you'll immediately see where it fails.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Mind blown

Comment: @user657267 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/146295

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BTW: I wonder why people write linked list implementations? Why not using the [c++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

```
void AddValue(intLinkedList MyList);
```

This generates a complete new MyList item. You should use a reference instead!

```
void AddValue(intLinkedList& MyList);
```

EDIT:

Why you use

```
 case 1: AddValue(MyList); break;
```

instead of:

```
 MyList.Add(...);
```

Any kind of indirection increase the risk of mistakes, complexity and unreadability. Your question is a very good example!

That is the first I see. Maybe there is a lot more.

Hope this is an entry point.

Comment: bingo. pro tip: when using printf (cout) to emit debugging statement's don't forget to output the address of the instances you're printing fields of ... that'll help find these errors where a copy is/isn't being made as you expect.

Comment: Oh my gosh. Of course.   It's a new list every time.   See I knew I was doing something dumb.   Lol.

Comment: _"I wonder why people write linked list implementations?"_ Probably because of silly homework assignments and bad teachers.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: @Klaus [tag:stl] probably isn't what you want to refer to. Why did you reject  my edit? If you just don't wan't to see my silly avatar appearing at your answer, just go to edit and add a newline in the end or such.

Comment: @Klaus Yeah, it seemed we're conflicting about some minor changes. Fixed that now. STL refers to a particular (early) implementation of the c++ standard library, that was proposed by HP back in the last century.